# How can I add mouse event listeners to an entire class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am trying to add a border around all items of a class when the mouse is hovering over it.  However, no matter which item I hover over, the border is always applied to the last item on the page.

Could anyone explain what is going on and how I may fix it?  Thanks.

```
function setAlertHovers(){
    var alerts = document.getElementsByClassName('alert');
    for(var i=0; i < alerts.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = alerts[i];
        obj.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){addBorder(obj);});
        obj.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){removeBorder(obj);});
    }
}

function addBorder(obj)
{
    obj.style.borderStyle = "solid";
}

function removeBorder(obj)
{
    obj.style.borderStyle = "none";
}

setAlertHovers();
```

Comment: this could be done with css only. why do you use javascript?

Comment: For direct children `.parentclass:hover > * {border: 1px solid #000}; ` or for all children  `.parentclass:hover * {border: 1px solid #000};`

Comment: This is just a test for what I actually want to do, which cannot be done in CSS alone. I'm just trying to learn how this works so I can do more complicated things.

Comment: You may pass this: obj.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){addBorder(this);});